# Combinatorics Expected Value without Replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose we have a deck of cards with 4 kings, 4 queens, and 4 jacks. Two cards are drawn uniformly at random without replacement. Let Q be the random variable representing the number of queens obtained. Find the expected value, variance, and standard deviation of Q.

To find the expected value, I would consider all possible cases.

1. 2 queens are drawn: $\frac{4}{12}*\frac{3}{11} = \frac{12}{132}$
2. 1 queen and 1 other: $\frac{4}{12}*\frac{8}{11} = \frac{32}{132}$
3. 1 other and 1 queen: $\frac{8}{12}*\frac{4}{11} = \frac{32}{132}$
4. 0 queens: $\frac{8}{12}*\frac{7}{11} = \frac{56}{132}$

Thus the expected Q is $2* \frac{12}{132} + 1*\frac{32}{132} + 1*\frac{32}{132} + 0*\frac{56}{132} = \frac{2}{3}.$

I am quite confused as to how I could continue this to find the variance and standard deviation of the distribution of the expected values. Any insights will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You have the complete distribution!  Just use the definition of variance to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

So far so good. Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of queens. Then the corresponding probabilities are

\begin{align*}
    &
P(X=2)=\frac{12}{132}=\frac1{11} \\  &P(X=1)=\frac{32}{132}+\frac{32}{132}=\frac{64}{132}=\frac{16}{33} \\ &P(X=0)=\frac{56}{132}=\frac{14}{33} \\ 
\end{align*}

Therefore the pdf is

$$f_X(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{14}{33}, \ \textrm{if} \ x=0 \\ \frac{16}{33}, \ \textrm{if} \ x=1 \\ \frac{1}{11}, \ \textrm{if} \ x=2 \\ 0, \ \textrm{elsewhere}  \end{cases}$$

The variance then is

$$Var(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-\left[\mathbb E (X) \right]^2 =\sum_{x=0}^2 x^2\cdot f_X(x)-\left[\sum_{x=0}^2 x\cdot f_X(x) \right]^2 $$

*Hints:* $\mathbb E(X^2)=\frac{28}{33}, \ \left[\mathbb E (X) \right]^2=\left(\frac23\right)^2=\frac{4}{9}$